# Dataset showing evolution of gene

Tags: gene, phylogeny, phylogenetics, clustering

As a way to exemplify how the hierarchical clustering of particular DNA sequences can be used to derive phylogenetic trees, I'm looking for a (even very small) dataset of the same genes (or other biological sequences) from different organisms (for example animals where the evolutionary tree is known). Do you have any pointers?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is. If you just want a bunch of sequences of homologous genes from different organisms, it is very easy to get them from places like NCBI or Ensembl. What is giving you trouble here? Do you need help using the standard databases, or do you need help in selecting the genes of interest? Could you please [edit] your question and explain what you are stuck on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're building a tree of different species, it's probably better to use protein sequences. A common resource is [Uniprot](https://www.uniprot.org/).

If you still want DNA sequences you can turn to [NCBI Nucleotide](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/nuccore).

Some examples that give decent trees: p53, TOP1, HBA.

A common way to construct a phylogenetic tree is to start with a [multiple sequence alignment (MSA)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_sequence_alignment).